# Unit Test for login in asp.net mvc 3

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, unit-testing

I have a problem testing a logon method using existing AccountController (made by MVC)...

I have this simple test method:

```
  [TestMethod]
  public void LogOnTest1() {
     AccountController controller = new AccountController();

     LogOnModel logonModel = new LogOnModel();
     logonModel.UserName = "test";
     logonModel.Password = "test1234";

     if ( controller.MembershipService == null ) {
        controller.MembershipService = new AccountMembershipService();
     }

     if ( controller.FormsService == null ) {
        controller.FormsService = new FormsAuthenticationService();
     }

     var result = controller.LogOn( logonModel, "" ) as ViewResult;

     Assert.AreEqual( "Index", result.ViewName );
  }
```

and the method defined in `AccountController`:

```
[HttpPost]
      public ActionResult LogOn( LogOnModel model, string returnUrl ) {
         if ( ModelState.IsValid ) {
            if ( MembershipService.ValidateUser( model.UserName, model.Password ) ) {
               FormsService.SignIn( model.UserName, model.RememberMe );
               if ( !string.IsNullOrEmpty( returnUrl ) ) {
                  return Redirect( returnUrl );
               } else {
                  return RedirectToAction( "Index", "Home" );
               }
            } else {
               ModelState.AddModelError( "", "The user name or password provided is incorrect." );
            }
         }

         // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
         return View( model );
      }
```

The above method is not defined/modified by me. Just created by when create an asp.net mvc project.

The problem is at line

`if ( MembershipService.ValidateUser( model.UserName,model.Password ) ) {`

which returns **always** false though I provided correct login info.

Where is my mistake ?

Comment: are you setting up Membership correctly in the Web.Config?

Comment: Looking for what ? What setting is needed to be set correctly ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, do not use `if` statements and other conditional logic in your tests. Also do not use concrete classes in your tests. If this test will fail, how will you know why? What was broken - controller or `AccountMembershipService`? Use abstract dependencies, which could be mocked.

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    private IMembershipService _membershipService;
    private IFormsService _formsService;

    public AccountController(IMembershipService membershipService,
                             IFormsService formsService)
    {
        _membershipService = membershipService;
        _formsService = formsService;
    }

    public ActionResult LogOn(LogOnModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        // implementation goes here
    }
}
```

And your tests:

```
[Test]
public void ShouldNotAcceptInvalidUser()
{
    // Arrange
    Mock<IMembershipService> membership = new Mock<IMembershipService>();
    membership.Setup(m => m.ValidateUser(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>()))
              .Returns(false);
    Mock<IFormsService> forms = new Mock<IFormsService>();
    var logonModel = new LogOnModel() { UserName = "", Password = "" };
    var controller = new AccountController(membership.Object, forms.Object);

    // Act
    var result = controller.LogOn(logonModel, "") as ViewResult;

    // Assert
    Assert.That(result.ViewName, Is.EqualTo("Index"));
    Assert.False(controller.ModelState.IsValid);
    Assert.That(controller.ModelState[""], 
                Is.EqualTo("The user name or password provided is incorrect."));
}
```

Interesting here is that you don't care which logon info you passed to controller. You mock response from membership service, which says logon was incorrect.

FEW TESTS MORE:

```
[Test]
public void ShouldRedisplayViewWhenModelIsNotValid()
{
   // Arrange        
   Mock<IMembershipService> membership = new Mock<IMembershipService>();
   Mock<IFormsService> forms = new Mock<IFormsService>();
   var model = new LogOnModel() { UserName = "", Password = "" };
   var controller = new AccountController(membership.Object, forms.Object);
   controller.ModelState.AddModelError("key", "error message");
   // Act
   var result = controller.LogOn(model, "") as ViewResult;
   // Assert
   Assert.That(result.ViewName, Is.EqualTo("LogOn"));
}

[Test]
public void ShouldSignInAndRedirectToIndex()
{
   // Arrange        
   Mock<IMembershipService> membership = new Mock<IMembershipService>();
  membership.Setup(m => m.ValidateUser(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>()))
             .Returns(true);
   Mock<IFormsService> forms = new Mock<IFormsService>();
   var model = new LogOnModel() { UserName = "", Password = "" };
   var controller = new AccountController(membership.Object, forms.Object);
   controller.ModelState.AddModelError("key", "error message");
   // Act
   var result = controller.LogOn(model, "") as ViewResult;

   // Assert
   forms.Verify(f => f.SignIn(model.UserName, model.RememberMe));
   Assert.That(result.ViewName, Is.EqualTo("Index"));
}
```

Comment: Crashing at `if ( MembershipService.ValidateUser( model.UserName, model.Password ) )`

Comment: Nice, have you changed your `LogOn` method implementation to use injected dependencies? And what error do you have?